# expo-cli is installed correctly but run with some errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I installed expo-cli globally on my machine to start working with react-native, the files of expo are located in the `C:\\users\username\node_modules`. Despite of installing it globally, windows command line (cmd) doesn't recognize the command expo. 
To make the expo command global, i added the path `C:\Users\username\node_modules\.bin` to environment variables, so the problem of using expo command is solved, i can use it to create a simple react-native application.

When i try to run the application using:

```
expo start --web
```

i get the following error:

```
D:\Testing\myapp>expo start --web
Starting project at D:\Testing\myapp
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a strange error. `ENOENT` means file not found and `spawn cmd` means it's trying to run something. One possible fix I found is, editting your `state.json` file in the location `HOMEPATH\.expo\state.json`.

Add  `"openDevToolsAtStartup": false` above the `PATH` line.

Hope this works for you.

*Note:* If you're using Windows 10, your `state.json` file will be in `C:\Users\your-username\.expo\state.json`